# Return overlapping strings between matches with Python3 regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

**Ideal result:**

I'd like to output,

```
[2+ years in buy side research, 2+ years in accounting]
```

From the below string which is a sentence in a job description,

```
'2+ years in buy side research or accounting'
```

So the `2+ years in` is repeated for both matches, and split on the `or`.

But I'm over my head writing complex regex.

**Currently result:**

```
str1 = '2+ years in buy side research or accounting'

pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9+]+ years|year)')

match_object = re.findall(pattern, str1)

=> ['2+ years']
```

Note: I tried to write this question's title in the clearest way possible but I'm happy to accept an edit if there's a clearer way to write it.

Comment: 1) Split at `or` 2) find a match for `\d+\+?\s+years` 3) iterate over array from 1st and append the match from 2nd to each

Comment: `re.sub('(2[+] years)(.*?)\\sor(.*)','\\1\\2,\\1\\3',st).split(',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach here is to match all words separated with whitespaces after `x years in` and then any number of words that follow after `or` conjunction, and once the matches are obtained build the resulting list by appending those words to the `x years in` part.

**NOTE it might deliver unexpected results if the strings have more words after the matching pattern after whitespaces.**

```
import re

str1 = '2+ years in buy side research or accounting'
pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9]+\+?\s*years?\s+in\s+)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?:\s+or\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)*)')
res = []
for m, n in re.findall(pattern, str1):
    for x in re.split(r'\s+or\s+', n):
        res.append("{}{}".format(m, x))

print(res) # => ['2+ years in buy side research', '2+ years in accounting']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/t2YIk4)

The regex is

```
([0-9]+\+?\s*years?\s+in\s+)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?:\s+or\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)*)
```

See the [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/kb5BRr/1). Details:

- `([0-9]+\+?\s*years?\s+in\s+)` - Group 1:

  - `[0-9]+`  - 1+ digits
  - `\+?` - an optional `+`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `years?` - `year` and an optional `s`
  - `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
  - `in` - an `in` word
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?:\s+or\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*` - 1+ word chars and then 0 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespaces and 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\s+or\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `or` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces and then followed with the pattern above